# в форме я поместил DataGrid, и соединил с бд, но в отладке выводится только строка

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: CourseLibrary - это папка проекта]

C#

```
database_entities context;

public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    context = new database_entities();
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = context.Avtor.ToList();
}
```

XAML

```xml
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="datagrid" ColumnWidth="*">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: А вы что ожидаете увидеть?

Comment: Почему в WPF у вас вдруг появились `Form`? В WPF нету форм, там есть `Window` (Окно). Далее, `DataGrid.ItemsSource` и `x:Name="datagrid"`... `DataGrid` != `datagrid`!! Затем, `DataGrid.ItemsSource = context.Avtor`, почему напрямую? Обычно так не делают. Сделайте класс, который вы установите как `DataContext` окна, в нем получите данные из базы, занесите их в класс, который будете привязывать, все это в коллекцию и уже затем привязываетесь без указания имен. Далее, `DataGrid` - у вас нету на экране `DataGrid`, его либо перекрывает что-то, либо он у вас вовсе не отображается.